# How to find the text height in pixel?

Tags: android

I dont know how to find the text height and width in pixels for the given text size in android. Anyone please help me to resolve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want just to set the height of the text in TextView. Please make it clear.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this can help:
[Measuring text height to be drawn on Canvas ( Android )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654321/measuring-text-height-to-be-drawn-on-canvas-android)

Answer (score 0):

An Excel with all text attributes for fixed size font can be found under https://github.com/ArminJo/android-blue-display/blob/master/TextWidth.xlsx .

The [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.joachimsmeyer.android.bluedisplay) as well as the function [drawFontTest()](https://github.com/ArminJo/android-blue-display/blob/master/src/de/joachimsmeyer/android/bluedisplay/RPCView.java) for generating the raw values used in the excel are also available in this repo.