# How to calculate line height containing TextView with specific height in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, height

I want to calculate the **line** (or layout) height (in DP) which contains only `TextView` as outcome of the `TextView text size` when using default line spacing ?
I.E. for this layout :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/minRow1col1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="11dp" />  

</LinearLayout>
```

What will be the layout/line height ? (any formula ? I don't need the value in run time)

Thanks !

Answer (score 16):

I don't know if this help you guys, but my solution to get the height of a line it's independent of the height of the layout, just take the font metrics like this:

```
myTextView.getPaint().getFontMetrics().bottom - myTextView.getPaint().getFontMetrics().top)
```

With this you will get the line height and for me, it's works with all words ( there are some chars like "g" or "j" that take some bottom space, the so called "descender" and so on ).

Comment: As I can remember, it's px.

Comment: It always is px when you deal with Paint and most Android Apis.

Comment: The answer yields the correct value, but it should be noted, that fontMetrics.top and fontMetrics.bottom don't actually stand for what you might think they stand for. Top: The maximum distance above the baseline for the tallest glyph in the font at a given text size. Bottom: The maximum distance below the baseline for the lowest glyph in the font at a given text size. The only reason why bottom - top leads to the correct value, is because top is negative: Remember, Y values increase going down, so those values will be positive, and values that measure distances going up will be negative.

Answer (score 5):

Try using the `TextPaint` object of `TextView`.

```
TextView tv = useTextView;
String text = tv.getText().toString();
Paint textPaint = tv.getPaint();

Rect textRect = new Rect();
textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), textRext);

int textHeight = textRect.height();
```

Per documentation of `Paint#getTextBound`:

> Return in bounds (allocated by the caller) the smallest rectangle that
>   encloses all of the characters, with an implied origin at (0,0).

Using the `Paint` object that the `TextView` uses will ensure it has the same parameters set that will be used to draw the text.

Comment: What will happen in case of a Spanned text. Each line may be of a different height. If you do a toString(), all the spanned information will be lost. How do you deal with such a case?

Comment: @Ashwin  TextView uses a Spanned internally for editable text.  You have to call it each time the text changes, but you should get the shortest height of the current text.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Paint.getTextBounds()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getTextBounds%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Rect%29):

```
String finalVal ="Hello";

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setTextSize(18);  
paint.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

Rect result = new Rect();
// Measure the text rectangle to get the height
paint.getTextBounds(finalVal, 0, finalVal.length(), result);

Log.d("WIDTH        :", String.valueOf(result.width()));
Log.d("HEIGHT       :", String.valueOf(result.height()));
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14277058/get-the-text-height-including-the-font-size-and-set-that-height).

Comment: I just need to know the `formula` not the size on run time.

Comment: what the numbers i get represent ? DP ? PX ? Because I measured my printscreens and got different values. Also, I get for 8 larger value than 9.

Comment: As the fonction getTextBounds is drawing a rectangke, I would say in DP so depending on the screen density of pixel, but I cannot be sure

Comment: @Pull: you only ever get DP when talking in the context of getResources(). Any bounds/positions are always in raw converted pixel values.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create custom `Textview` and use `getActualHeight()` method. Where the **formula** is: `actualHeight=(int) ((getLineCount()-1)*getTextSize());`

```
public class TextViewHeightPlus extends TextView {
    private static final String TAG = "TextView";
    private int actualHeight=0;


    public int getActualHeight() {
        return actualHeight;
    }

    public TextViewHeightPlus(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TextViewHeightPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    public TextViewHeightPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }

   @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        actualHeight=0;

        actualHeight=(int) ((getLineCount()-1)*getTextSize());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For my usecase I started out by assuming that the line height is a linear function that depends on the textsize, something like:

```
line_height = text_size*some_constant
```

Now some_constant is probably a function as well, that depends on what font you use. But since in my requirements the font was static, I was able to calculate some_constant and use repeatedly in a safe way.

To clue you in a little a bit more on my usecase, I was scaling a piece of multiline text in  order to fit it in a box of variable height.

In my usecase I wanted to go a step further and included the space multiplier. It was quite simple, as it was just another factor in the equation:

```
line_height = text_size*some_constant*spacing_multiplier
```

In summary if you stick to the same font and you calculate the value of some_constant once, you can (probably) get your function.

DISCLAIMER: I say "probably" a lot because I haven't tested a lot of my assumptions, but like I said, it worked for a decently complex usecase.