# Calculate a height of specific line of textview

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-layout, textview

I want to calculate a height of specific textview line. Let's suppose my textview has 3 lines of text and I want to calculate height of the third line. How to achieve that?

I was trying this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40133086/21172734 but it gets the whole textview height, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you referred to computes the whole textView height as you described; if you want to calculate only the height of the third line or any other line, you can use TextView's Layout methods called `getLinesBounds`.

Here is how it goes:

- You get the vertical position or the y-coordinates of that line from the top using `getLineTop()`, in which you pass `2` as an argument, which means the third line since the index starts from 0.
- You do the same from the bottom using `getLineBottom()` with the same argument.
- You subtract the difference as a final result.

Here is the full code:

```kotlin
val thirdLineTop = textView.layout.getLineTop(2)
val thirdLineBottom = textView.layout.getLineBottom(2)
val thirdLineHeight = thirdLineBottom - thirdLineTop
```

I tried that but It raised some errors, the issue is the `layout` object of the Textview will be null in the `onCreate` since the TextView hasn't been Laid out YET, so we need to wait until that TextView is laid out and have a valid layout object to start using the above code, so I added a layout observer listner like the following to test the code:

```kotlin
val tv = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tva)
tv.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
     val thirdLineTop = tv.layout.getLineTop(2)
     val thirdLineBottom = tv.layout.getLineBottom(2)
     println("Total height is $thirdLineBottom - $thirdLineTop")
}
```

I hope this would work for you!