# making textView wrap its text vertically

Tags: android, textview

I used this code:

```
Rect bounds=new Rect();
tv.getPaint().getTextBounds(text,0, text.length(),bounds);
float textWidth=bounds.width();
float textHeight=bounds.height();
```

and it works well horizontally...
also vertical size is ok...
but the text is painted in a position lower than what I expect...

these links was not useful:

[get text height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14277058/get-the-text-height-including-the-font-size-and-set-that-height)

[auto scale textview text to fit within bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds)

what should I change?

[view and its text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfKFO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set your layout params to WRAP_CONTENT for the height. If your text is in a LinearLayout it would look like this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.WRAP_CONTENT);
myTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

If you're using a XML layout just set your TextView's layout_height to wrap_content. If the text is still painted lower than you expect check whats the padding set to the TextView.