# Draw text inside a filled rectangle using Canvas Android

Tags: android, canvas, view, drawing

How to draw a filled rectangle with specified bounds and inside that rectangle text to be drawn using Canvas Android ?? I tried

```
mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
canvas.drawText(mText, x, y, mPaint);
mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
canvas.drawRect(x, y, x + w, y + h, mPaint);
```

but text is not inside of that rectangle. Can any buddy tell me how to draw a rectangle  surrounding specified text with consideration of text size ??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here i have hardcoded x and y values. You can change them

```
        mpaint= new Paint();
        mpaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mpaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        paint2= new Paint();
        paint2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint2.setTextSize(50);  //set text size
        float w = paint2.measureText(s)/2;
        float textSize = paint2.getTextSize();


        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            paint2.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
            canvas.drawRect(300-w, 300 - textsize, 300 + w, 300, mpaint);
            canvas.drawText(s, 300, 300 ,paint2); //x=300,y=300    
        }
```

Edit :

Its bad a idea to call `measureText` in `onDraw`. You can do that outside of `onDraw`.

There is a video on also about performance and why you should avoid allocations in `onDraw`. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HAK5acHQ53E

Resulting snap shot

[image]

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, the rectangle should cover only text area and the position and text size may change dynamically. Depends on the text size and length i 've to draw rectangle ??

Comment: Why is there an empty space in the drawn rectangle? drawtext by default uses some top padding, if yes how to avoid that?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber it must be copy paste mistake. I copied the code from the editor. I forgot and take that out.

Comment: @vikki_logs you can always play with the values. left , right ,top and bottom to get it right. this is just a sample

Comment: Still bad solution to call `measureText()` in `onDraw()`, twice.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber agree i answered this long back and i will rectify this soon.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber edited and post a link that also explains why we should avoid allocations in onDraw and thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: What if textsize is greater than 300??, In this case text gets cut from left.

Comment: @Nainal measure the text height and width and then draw the rect https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654321/measuring-text-height-to-be-drawn-on-canvas-android

Answer (score 6):

If you have to center the text inside de rect you have use this code

```
    mpaint= new Paint();
    mpaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    mpaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    paint2= new Paint();
    paint2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    paint2.setTextSize(50);  //set text size
    float w = paint2.measureText(s)/2;
    float textSize = paint2.getTextSize();


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        paint2.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        Rect rect = new Rect(300-w, 300 - textsize, 300 + w, 300);
        canvas.drawRect(rect, mpaint);
        canvas.drawText(s, rect.centerX(), rect.centerY() ,paint2); // center text inside rect
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This might be very late for this particular query but I think many will find this answer useful. So, the problem with the Canvas for any CustomView is that, you can get the width for a particular text, but it's not that easy to get the height of the text. Also if you are using `canvas.drawText(....)` with simple **Paint** object, you can not draw multi line text. So, use the below code within your `onDraw()` method.

```
String displayText = "Hello World";
int mainTextPositionX = getWidth() / 2 ;
int mainTextPositionY = getHeight() / 2;

StaticLayout textStaticLayout;
TextPaint textPaint;
textPaint = new TextPaint();
textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
textPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
textPaint.setTextSize(convertDpToPixel(30, context));
textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
highlightedRectPaint = new Paint();

highlightedRectPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
highlightedRectPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
highlightedRectPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
highlightedRectPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        textStaticLayout = StaticLayout
                .Builder
                .obtain(displayText, 0, displayText.length(), textPaint, (int) textPaint.measureText(displayText))
                .build();
    }else{
        textStaticLayout = new StaticLayout(
                displayText, textPaint, (int)textPaint.measureText(displayText), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);
    }

    Rect highlightedTextBorderRect = new Rect();
    highlightedTextBorderRect.top = mainTextPositionY-20;
    highlightedTextBorderRect.left = mainTextPositionX- 
    ((int)textPaint.measureText(displayText)/2)-20;
    highlightedTextBorderRect.right = mainTextPositionX+ 
    ((int)textPaint.measureText(displayText)/2) + 20;
    highlightedTextBorderRect.bottom = mainTextPositionY+ 
    (int)textStaticLayout.getHeight()+20;

    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(mainTextPositionX, mainTextPositionY);
    textStaticLayout.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();

    canvas.drawRect(highlightedTextBorderRect,highlightedRectPaint);
```

just make sure that, you declare all the objects and variable outside of the `draw()` method. And this will draw a rectangle outline around the text with multi line support. If you want the rectangle to have a fill, then just use the **highlightedRectPaint** and change the `setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL)`.  Hope that helps.