# What is TextPaint bgColor attribute?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm playing around with `TextPaint` on Android. I'd like to draw text with a background color on a `Canvas` without drawing a Rect behind it. I thought `bgColor` would do this, but apparently not. And nothing is said about it in the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextPaint#bgColor).

Interestingly though, if I apply that paint to the paint of an `EditText`, the background color appears, ***sometimes***. Not sure why, maybe some function similar to invalidate is called somewhere:

```kotlin
val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edit)
val paint = TextPaint().apply {
    textSize = 120f
    typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT
    bgColor = Color.BLUE
}
editText.paint.set(paint)
```

So actually, if you guys have any idea of what's happening in one case or the other, that would be very helpful!

Comment: like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609426/draw-text-inside-a-filled-rectangle-using-canvas-android?

Comment: yeah, basically a background color behind each letter, like you would have on any editor such as Google Doc. I can do it with a Rect that's no problem. I just can't understand this `bgColor` attribute.