# How do I indent a text line in TextView in android?

Tags: android

I am writing a text in android which take more than two lines now my problem is how I indent the second line my text lines are.

```
1.my name is qadeer hussain

iam fine how  Ru.
```

but I want

```
1.my name is qadeer hussain

     iam fine how  Ru.
```

here the second line not start right below the one but it right below the name

Answer (score 33):

Use a `LeadingMarginSpan.Standard` with a `SpannableString`, or if you also need bullets use a `BulletSpan`:

Just create a function like this:

```
static SpannableString createIndentedText(String text, int marginFirstLine, int marginNextLines) {
    SpannableString result=new SpannableString(text);
    result.setSpan(new LeadingMarginSpan.Standard(marginFirstLine, marginNextLines),0,text.length(),0);
    return result;
}
```

And then, everytime you need an indented line you can do:

```
myTextView.setText(createIndentedText("my text that's gonna be indented", 10, 10));
```

The first parameter is the indentation of the first line, the second parameter is the indentation of the next lines, just in case you want to indent the first line differently to the following ones.

Comment: can u please elaborate it more

Comment: Works great. Should be the Accepted answer for this question!

Comment: it's perfect. By the way, with \n in a single string, it restarts the spanning for each new line!

Answer (score 5):

Try using a `\t` before what you want to indent. Use more if you need to indent it further

Comment: but how i know that from where my string display on next line because different android devices have different screen sizes

Comment: well, you can actually predict that, try looking here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654321/measuring-text-height-to-be-drawn-on-canvas-android
 All you have to do now is to check your screen size and compare to the text size, to calculate how much of it will be in the same line. Now it all comes down to what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

You can use \t for spacing and \n for new line. you can use as many new lines and \t spacing for your text according to your needs. For your example:

```
    textView.setSingleLine(false);
    textView.setText("1.my name is qadeer hussain\n\tiam fine how  Ru.");
```

Comment: but i dont know from where my string break and display on next line because different android devices have different screen size