# What is the unit for TextPaint setTextSize in Android?

Tags: android

The dev. docs does not say anything about the unit. Pixels, dps, cm?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setTextSize(float)

From experimenting, the most likely answer is pixels, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is pixels, since setText() is native method and in `Paint.h` native call transforms the float to scalar value, then draws it. Of course, you can apply dip for support various screens by:

```
 float textSize =  TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size), getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```