# How to center domain label below bar in a bar chart?

Tags: android, androidplot

Currently, each bar's domain label appears below the left hand side of each bar, as pictured here:

[image]

Is there a way to position labels below each bar's center ?

Comment: It wouldn't make sense at all (to me, at least). Each label should indicate which bar it belongs to by being positioned exactly under it.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "exactly under it", but to me they should be under it of course, but between each bar's edge, not below the left edge

Comment: If I got you well, you mean "each one centered to the corresponding bar width". Maybe you'll have to take the source of the library and make your own implementation. I did some modifications to aChartEngine - not only to make it slimmer, but also to fit my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
XYGraphWidget.LineLabelStyle style = plot.getGraph().getLineLabelStyle(XYGraphWidget.Edge.BOTTOM);
style.getPaint().setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are doing that on canvas.

1. You already know the width of the bar.
2. Measure the text size (width) to be displayed using
   [Measuring text height to be drawn on Canvas ( Android )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654321/measuring-text-height-to-be-drawn-on-canvas-android)
3. `(barWidth/2 - textWidth/2) + barLeft` should do, i think.

Comment: Your answer doesn't help in the context of an AndroidPlot