# Measuring tight bounds box of multiline text

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-graphics, staticlayout

I'm drawing a multiline text on a canvas using `StaticLayout`, and I want to measure the most tight bounds box around the text before drawing, (the text could be in different sizes, fonts, styles etc...), I want something like that:

```
Size measureText(String text, float size, Font font, etc...)
```

and I want it to return the most tight bounds box around the text, i.e. (if we are talking about the pixels of the text):

```
(leftest_pixel - rightest_pixel, highest_pixel - lowest_pixels)
```

If the text was single line, I could do:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
...
paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, size, rect);
```

But since the text could have multiple lines I must take in consider the linespacing and the glyphs descent and all the other font parameters... so the next option will be to use `StaticLayout` with `maximalLineWidth` (in order to break the lines), but `StaticLayout` doesn't calculate the most tight box, it will add a bit paddings in the top and in the bottom (because it basically multiple the number of lines by the max line height):

for example, the green box is the result of measuring with `StaticLayout` and the red box is the box I want to receive:

[image]
[image]
[image]

How can I do it?
Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer, but have you tried the 2 other methods here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42091739/608312

Comment: @JakeSteam yes, the other methods won't help here because I must use the static layout in order to break the lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the *StaticLayout* then determine the bounds of each individual line using methods from *TextPaint*. The boundaries for the entire multi-line text is the top boundary of the top line, the bottom boundary of the last line and the left-most and right-most boundaries of all the lines.

Here is a sample custom view that demonstrate this concept. The layout is simply the custom view with a width of `200dp` and a height of `wrap_content`.

[image]

[image]

**MyStaticText**

```
public class MyStaticText extends View {
    private final String mText = "This is some longer text to test multiline layout.";
    private TextPaint mTextPaint;
    private StaticLayout mStaticLayout;
    private final Paint mRectPaint = new Paint();

    public MyStaticText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mTextPaint = new TextPaint();
        mTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(FONT_SIZE * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        mTextPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        mRectPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mRectPaint.setStrokeWidth(2f);
        mRectPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int widthAskedFor = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            mStaticLayout = new StaticLayout(mText, mTextPaint, widthAskedFor, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0, false);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("View width must be exactly specified.");
        }

        int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int height;
        if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            height = mStaticLayout.getHeight() + getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("View height must be 'wrap_content'.");
        }
        setMeasuredDimension(widthAskedFor, height);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        mStaticLayout.draw(canvas);

        // Start with bounds of first line.
        Rect textBounds = getLineBounds(0);

        // Check bounds of last line since it will be the bottom of the bounding rectangle.
        Rect lineBounds = getLineBounds(mStaticLayout.getLineCount() - 1);
        if (lineBounds.bottom > textBounds.bottom) {
            textBounds.bottom = lineBounds.bottom;
        }

        // Now check all lines for min left bound and max right bound.
        for (int line = 0; line < mStaticLayout.getLineCount(); line++) {
            lineBounds = getLineBounds(line);
            if (lineBounds.left < textBounds.left) {
                textBounds.left = lineBounds.left;
            }
            if (lineBounds.right > textBounds.right) {
                textBounds.right = lineBounds.right;
            }
        }
        canvas.drawRect(textBounds, mRectPaint);
    }

    private Rect getLineBounds(int line) {
        int firstCharOnLine = mStaticLayout.getLineStart(line);
        int lastCharOnLine = mStaticLayout.getLineVisibleEnd(line);
        String s = mText.substring(firstCharOnLine, lastCharOnLine);

        // bounds will store the rectangle that will circumscribe the text.
        Rect bounds = new Rect();

        // Get the bounds for the text. Top and bottom are measured from the baseline. Left
        // and right are measured from 0.
        mTextPaint.getTextBounds(s, 0, s.length(), bounds);
        int baseline = mStaticLayout.getLineBaseline(line);
        bounds.top = baseline + bounds.top;
        bounds.bottom = baseline + bounds.bottom;

        return bounds;
    }

    private static final int FONT_SIZE = 48;
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/Cheticamp/BoundedTextDemo) is a demo app that has a more generalized solution.