# Dynamically calculate text size to fill the space of rectangle

Tags: android, canvas

I have rectf which is drawn in canvas, based on this rectf I have drawn simple bubble alike. I want my text should be inside this bubble.

Here is what I have tried.

I have a textPaint which is initialized with textSize 30, and I'm building static layout like this.

```
staticLayout = StaticLayout.Builder.obtain(text, start, end, textPaint, width)
        .setAlignment(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL)
        .setTextDirection(TextDirectionHeuristics.LTR)
        .setLineSpacing(0, 1.0f)
        .setIncludePad(false)
        .setEllipsizedWidth(10)
        .setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.START)
        .setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
        .setBreakStrategy(Layout.BREAK_STRATEGY_SIMPLE)
        .setHyphenationFrequency(Layout.HYPHENATION_FREQUENCY_NONE)
        .setJustificationMode(Layout.JUSTIFICATION_MODE_NONE)
        .build()
```

From this static layout I'm getting my TextLayout's height as `staticLayout.height`

I want my text layout height should not exceed by 70% of my bounds height, so that my text will be always inside my bounds.

```
float maxTextLayoutHeight = bounds.height() * 0.70f;
```

And my actual static layout's height

```
height = staticLayout.height;
```

From these two values I recalculate text size and applied it to my text paint with following code.

```
annotationTextSize = (maxTextLayoutHeight / height) * 13;
annotationTextSize = annotationTextSize * 0.80f;
if (annotationTextSize < 25) annotationTextSize = 25; //Limited to min 25
if (annotationTextSize > 99) annotationTextSize = 99; //Limited to max 99
textPaint.setTextSize(annotationTextSize);
```

**Here is some images**

**With small text size:**

[image]

[image]

**Text size looks perfect:**

[image]

[image]

**Text size looks bigger:**

[image]

[image]

Any improved calculation will be much helpful.

Comment: Is the text always going to be what you show in the images?

Comment: Have you read the comments in [this answer to Measuring text height to be drawn on Canvas ( Android )](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42091739/295004)

Comment: @HelderSepulveda, No it will change...

Comment: If the text could be other than what you show, you need to include the text in your calculations, measure the text with an average size if is bigger reduce size, if smaller increase and loop until you get something that fits

Comment: Have you thought about using an [Autosizing TextView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview) and grabbing the _StaticLayout_ from the _TextView_? You would set up the bounds and let the _TextView_ do the work.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think that you will be able to determine the size of the laid out text until it is laid out. Internally, autosized *TextViews* do measurements of the text to find the best fit through a binary search that lays out the text for each candidate text size. (See *AppCompatTextViewAutoSizeHelper* [here](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:appcompat/appcompat/src/main/java/androidx/appcompat/widget/AppCompatTextViewAutoSizeHelper.java;l=696).

You can borrow some code from the *AppCompatTextViewAutoSizeHelper* or use something simpler as the following although it will not be as quick:

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    var textSize = 99
    while (mStaticLayout == null) {
        var layout: StaticLayout
        textPaint.textSize = textSize.toFloat()
        layout = makeStaticLayout(mText, 0, mText.length, textPaint, width)
        if (layout.height < height || textSize == 25) {
            mStaticLayout = layout
        } else {
            textSize--
        }
    }
    mStaticLayout?.draw(canvas)
}
```

You could also use the internal workings of *TextView* to get a *StaticLayout* that can be drawn to a canvas.

```
private fun makeAutoSizeView(
    @StringRes textId: Int, width: Int, height: Int
): AppCompatTextView {
    return AppCompatTextView(this).apply {
        layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(width, height)
        TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(
            this,
            TextViewCompat.AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_UNIFORM
        )
        text = resources.getString(textId)
    }
}

private fun getAutoSizeLayout(width: Int, height: Int): StaticLayout {
    val autoSizeTextView = makeAutoSizeView(R.string.good_to_see_you, width, height)
    val widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
    val heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
    autoSizeTextView.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec)
    autoSizeTextView.layout(0, 0, width, height)
    return autoSizeTextView.layout as StaticLayout
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I calculated the height of text to be rendered using the following method. Might be helpful

```
private fun getMultilineTextHeight(text: CharSequence, textPaint: TextPaint, width: Int): Int {

        val alignment = Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL
        val spacingMultiplier = 1f
        val spacingAddition = 0f
        val includePadding = false

        val staticLayout =
                StaticLayout(text, textPaint, width, alignment, spacingMultiplier, spacingAddition, includePadding)

        return staticLayout.height

    }
```

Comment: But I want recommended text size based on static layout height and rectf height... When apply that recommended text size to text paint, the text will occupy max space from that rect.