# Text in jetpak compose have automatic padding when having a big text

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Text on my screen which have a size of 180sp. But it automatically has padding at the top and bottom. How to remove that padding?

```
BasicText(
            text = temperature,
            color = ColorProducer { Black },
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge
        )
```

Comment: I have asked the same question few times ago. You can check my solution or read usable comments under question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75712788/how-to-draw-text-without-paddings